# What's printed by the following Pyhon code?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, lexicographic

```py
animals = ['horse', 'Pig', 'dog', 'Owl', 'lion', 'Hare', 'baboon', 'Fish', 'tiger', 'Zebra', 'Cow', 'Mouse', 'quail', 'Elephant']

for animal in animals:

    if (animal >= 'M') and (animal <= 'Z'):

        print(animal)
```

Question 1:

How to understand  `(animal >= 'M') and (animal <= 'Z')` ?

Question 2:

The correct answer is `Pig` `Owl` `Mouse`, why `Zebra` is not printed in this case?

Comment: Strings are compared alphabetically e.g. "A" < "B"

Comment: Note for the future that questions with more than one question within them are liable to be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like zvone pointed out, string are compared alphabetically and therefor Zebra is not printed.

The alphabetic order in this case would be.

X
Y
Z
Za
Zebra

Answer (score 0):

1. Animals that come alphabetically between "M" and "Z".
2. "Zebra" comes after "Z" when sorted in python.

Answer (score 0):

from a to z ordering is like that in alpha characters:

> ["a","aa","aaa" ... "ab","aba","abaa" ... "b"... "z", "za", "zaa" ...
> "zebra" ... "zzzzz" ...]

depending on their string representation of ascii equvalent is a < b < c ... < y < z and z always comes before z* (asterix means any)

Answer (score 0):

1. it will print animals that start from letters between 'M' and 'Y' (both included) and also single letter "Z".
2. because "Z" < "Zebra"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).